# ProgressDialog firing only after setContentView()

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "Logging In...");
```

And it is supposed to run from the top of the method and through until it reaches an end. Here is the block that is execute on authorization success:

```
if(writeSuccess){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pDialog.dismiss();
    setContentView(R.layout.auth);
}
```

But the `ProgressDialog` will not fire. But if I comment out it's dismissal it will fire *after* the ContentView has been switched. Anybody have any idea or remedy to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do what you want. On onPreExecute, create and display the dialog, on doInBackground, make your Login, and on onPostExecute dismiss the dialog previously created.